# Fluid simulation not working after parenting to animated object

Tags: fluid-simulation

I know this is a common question, but I already tried Apply Transform and checking properties of the fluid simulation. I got fluid working and rendering fine and the final step was animating the object it's parented to. After animating, the fluid stopped baking/rendering and looks like a low-poly gray blob.

[.blend file with fluid sim](https://github.com/01binary/fluidhelp/raw/master/flask-casting.blend)

If someone has a chance to look I would appreciate it! It's probably going to help others who search for this problem later.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blob is a cube. It look like a blob because the subdivision surface modfier. The domain is not a fluid source or a fluid object. The domain is the border of your simulation. So you have to increase the domain's size to include the jars and add a fluid object inside it instead your current domain object. Don't move the domain. Add fluid>>obstacle to the jars.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/fluid/types/index.html